# IF Condition doesnt work

Tags: java, android

Am trying to make an `IF condition` but it's not working well. I want when the `EditText` is `null`, the user doesn't go to the next Activity.

when it's filled it goes to the next activity after a button press.

```
Name = is my EditText assignment 

one_next_diaspora_bt = is the Button.
```

Below is my Code:

```
final String Name = name_diaspora_edt.getText().toString();
one_next_diaspora_bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(Name.matches("")){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Make sure that you have filled your name please !!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                else {

                    Intent i = new Intent(Diaspora.this,DiasporaTwo.class);
                    i.putExtra("Name",Name);
                    i.putExtra("Age",Age);
                    i.putExtra("Gender",Gender);
                    i.putExtra("MaritalStatus",MaritalStatus);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: final String Name = name_diaspora_edt.getText().toString();
write indide of onclick functions

Comment: Sorry but in your origianal question `Name` was a textfield! Now it is a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
one_next_diaspora_bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final String Name = name_diaspora_edt.getText().toString().trim();
                if(Name.matches("")){


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Make sure that you have filled your name please !!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }

                else{



                    Intent i = new Intent(Diaspora.this,DiasporaTwo.class);
                    i.putExtra("Name",Name);
                    i.putExtra("Age",Age);
                    i.putExtra("Gender",Gender);
                    i.putExtra("MaritalStatus",MaritalStatus);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
if (Name.getText() != null && Name.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
```

And follow the Java naming convention. variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: @jhildstack Thanks for improvement

Answer (score 2):

Change your condition to this:

```
 if(edt.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
  }
```

Or

```
if (edt.getText().trim().equals("")){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
if (Name != null && Name.equalIgnoreCase("null") && Name.trim().equalIgnoreCase("")){

}else
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `TextUtils.isEmpty`, it will check null and empty as well. TextUtils is a built-in class in package `android.text`

```
 if(android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would say, you really should follow naming conventions.
But you need to grab the `String` that lives inside of your `EditText` and compare it with `.equals` like so:

```
if(name.getText().toString().equals("")){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)){  
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Make sure that you have filled your name please !!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Use android default validation, TextUtils class

Answer (score 1):

Use `TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)` instead of `Name.matches("")`.

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence str) >> Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.
```

**Try this:**

```
final String Name = name_diaspora_edt.getText().toString();
one_next_diaspora_bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Make sure that you have filled your name please !!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Intent i = new Intent(Diaspora.this, DiasporaTwo.class);
                i.putExtra("Name", Name);
                i.putExtra("Age", Age);
                i.putExtra("Gender", Gender);
                i.putExtra("MaritalStatus", MaritalStatus);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check the EditText with this method , equals() works with Strings.

Try This

```
String data = Name.getText().toString();
```

Then

```
if(data.isEmpty()){
}
```